# Error displayed when processing real-time(socket) data of ag-grid(community)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When I continuously update the data on the `ag-grid`, the data is lumped in the first column.
I'm looking for a way to make the data grid always fully visible and the new data only update on certain cell.

Currently, I'm trying to listen to the socket's message and update to the 'bids' array. That currently doesn't work when the table keeps showing the wrong UI. Socket time is about `200ms/time`

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (lastMessage !== null && readyState === ReadyState.OPEN && isReady) {
        const paseData = lastMessage.data.split("|");
        if (paseData[0].length > 7) return;
        const data = {
            id: paseData[0] || ' ',
            max: paseData[58] || ' ',
            min: paseData[59] || ' ',
            tc: paseData[60] || ' ',
            db_p_3: paseData[5] || ' ',
            db_kl_3: paseData[6] || ' ',
            db_p_2: paseData[3] || ' ',
            db_kl_2: paseData[4] || ' ',
            db_p_1: paseData[1] || ' ',
            db_kl_1: paseData[2] || ' ',
            kl_p: paseData[75] || ' ',
            kl_cl: paseData[52] || ' ',
            kl_kl: paseData[51] || ' ',
            dm_p_1: paseData[21] || ' ',
            dm_kl_1: paseData[22] || ' ',
            dm_p_2: paseData[23] || ' ',
            dm_kl_2: paseData[24] || ' ',
            dm_p_3: paseData[25] || ' ',
            dm_kl_3: paseData[26] || ' ',//
            high: paseData[43] || ' ',
            low: paseData[45] || ' ',
            nn_du: paseData[46] || ' ',
            total: paseData[53] || ' ',
            nn_b: paseData[2] || ' ',
            nn_s: paseData[2] || ' ',
            };
            // console.log('lastMessage',lastMessage);
            const newData = [...bids]
            const _index = bids.findIndex(x => x.id === data.id);
            // console.log(_index);
            // const _index = -1
            // prevCountRef.current = data
            if (_index > -1) {
                // table.value[_index] = data;
                newData[_index] = data
            } else {
                // const newData = [...trading.value, data];
                newData.push(data)
                // trading.value = newData;
                // table.value =[...table.value,data]
            }
            // console.log(newData);
            
            setBids(newData)
        }
    }, [lastMessage, isReady]);
```